# Display post content with fancybox

Tags: php, wordpress, fancybox-3

I'm trying to display the post content in a fancybox, and it's almost working good except after clicking on the link it shows only the content of the first post.

So I came across the idea to add the posts ID to the data-src, but for some reason my code is not adding the ID.

```
<ul>
          <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'rm', 'showposts' => 20, 'order' => 'ASC'); $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
          <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
          <?php $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'city_council_candidates', true );

          $postsData[$row]['links'][$i] = [
            'id' => get_the_id(),
          ];

          foreach($postsData as $key => $value) :
            $links = $value['links'];

            echo '<pre>'; echo var_dump($links); echo '</pre>';
          ?>

          <li class="candidates-wrapper col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
            <a data-fancybox data-src="#selectableModal-<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" href="javascript:;">
              <div class="candidates-img">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
              </div><!-- .news_img -->
              <div class="candidates-name">
                <?php echo $meta['name']; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="candidates-surname">
                <?php echo $meta['surname']; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="candidates-constituency">
                <?php echo $meta['constituency']; ?>
              </div>

              <div style="display: none;max-width:500px;" id="selectableModal-<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">
                <h2>
                  <?php echo $meta['name']; ?><?php echo $meta['surname']; ?>
                <h2>
                <p>
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                </p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li><!-- .news-wrapper -->

          <?php
            endforeach;
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
          ?>
        </ul>
```

As you can see I also added the var_dump function to check if the `$links` are getting any ID's from the query and the ID's are passed there.

In the console the link looks like this `<a data-fancybox="" data-src="#selectableModal-" href="javascript:;">`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `$value['id']` does not exist. Your $postData array has the structure `$postsData[$row]['links'][$i]['id']`, and you are looping over the first level of that, so $value inside your foreach loop is still structured like `['links'][$i]['id']`

Comment: Thank you @misorude, now it works great :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="display: none; max-width:500px;" id="selectableModal">
  <h2>name + surname<h2>
  <p>content</p>
 </div>
```

You shouldn't put the style display:none inline with id="selectableModal" element. it shouldn't be there, it might show the fancybox but not the content for it will not show the content. Maybe override the content with display: block!important; when fancybox shows.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. The content is showing after the click but only from the first post even if I click the 9th post.

Comment: on the <a data-fancybox> add the code post so it knows that they are related.. like <a data-fancybox="post">

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that output of `<?php echo $value['id'] ?>` is empty, therefore most likely you have multiple elements having the same id - `#selectableModal-` and that causes your issue.

Sorry, I am not WP expert, but maybe try replacing `$value['id']` with `$post->ID`.